# Variable not accessible after thread start() method

Tags: java

So this is my code for the class that implements Runnable.

```
public class SeedDownload implements Runnable {

    private StringBuilder htmlSB;
    private String bingSeed;

    public SeedDownload(StringBuilder string) {
        htmlSB = string;
    }

    public void run() {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("class=\"b_algo\"><h2><a href=\"(.+?)\" h=\"");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(htmlSB);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            bingSeed = matcher.group(1);
            System.out.println(bingSeed);
        }
    } //End of run

    public String getUrlLink() {
        return bingSeed;
    }

}
```

And this is the code in my main class.

```
StringBuilder htmlResult = PageRead.readPage(String.format("https://bing.com/search?q=%s", query));
     System.out.println(htmlResult);
    SeedDownload sdBing = new SeedDownload(htmlResult);
    Thread bingThread = new Thread(sdBing);
    bingThread.start();

    System.out.println(sdBing.getUrlLink());
```

And this is the output when ran.

"    null

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world_program "

Apparently, the print in the run method could access the the variable, whereas in the main class, it couldn't. Is it something to do with the run() method being stopped and the contents of it not being accessible?

Comment: did you try putting breakpoint and debug it?

Comment: Did you consider waiting for the thread to *execute*? Did you consider making the variable `volatile`? What exactly is the purpose of this trivial thread?

Comment: You seem to be lacking a basic understand of how threads work. You can't make any assumptions about where your thread is holding after calling `start()`, unless you add some synchronization or wait for it to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main problems

When you are running

```
 bingThread.start();
 System.out.println(sdBing.getUrlLink());
```

you are assuming that the `Thread` has started and has already assigned a value to `bingSeed` - this maybe not the case, so before calling `getUrlLink` ensure that the `Thread` has finished by adding

```
bingThread.join();
```

Secondly, to ensure that the *most-up-to-date* value of `bingSeed` is being used make it volatile as in

```
private volatile String bingSeed;
```

Comment: `Thread.join()` has a *happens-before* edge. `volatile` is unnecessary.

Comment: @shmosel Thanks, I thought that might be the case.

Answer (score 1):

You just have a volatilness issue, the getter is not retrieving the updated value of the string, so your string object must be volatile! so you can be sure that you get the updated value when you call the getter

change this

```
private String bingSeed;
```

with

```
private volatile String bingSeed;
```

from oracle [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html):

> Using volatile variables reduces the risk of memory consistency
>   errors, because any write to a volatile variable establishes a
>   happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same
>   variable. This means that changes to a volatile variable are always
>   visible to other threads. What's more, it also means that when a
>   thread reads a volatile variable, it sees not just the latest change
>   to the volatile, but also the side effects of the code that led up the
>   change.

Comment: It's not (necessarily) a volatile issue. There's a glaring race condition.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that it is not accessible, but because the modification of the variable bingSeed happens in **another thread** than the main thread, the System.out.println() of the main thread executes WHEN the bingSeed is still null

you have options here, either wait for the thread to finish using **synchronisation** or submit the thread to an **Executors Service** and poll the result

Answer (score 0):

The thread is producing its result independently, performing asynchronous or background processing.So the thread will produce the result independently, but the java program may have gone far already, after its request to this thread.So no result is got to the java program,but the result is given by thread correctly.This is why it is null. Use `volatile` keyword for this.

Answer (score 0):

In your code there are two possiblities of getting null value i.e

1) matcher.find() gives false result in that case you will get a non 
   initialized value i.e null.

2) your print statement is executing before your thread is assigning value 
   to bingSeed

you can check this by providing true value to if block of matcher.find() 
in this case you will get null value if matcher doesnt have any match.

Also, for 2nd point you can sleep your thread to wait and let the bingSeed initialize.

```
     `bingThread.start();
     Thread.sleep(millis);  // it will halt your main thread and you will get your variable value.
     System.out.println(sdBing.getUrlLink());`
```

i tried it and it worked fine after these checks